# How to display main layout from layout 2 button from activity?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, mobile-application

I have one activity with two layouts one is main layout and the other layout name is layout2. Both layout files contain one button each. it works good if i press button on main layout it take me to layout 2 but the problem is when i click button on layout 2 to take me back to main layout i does not work.

**MainActivity**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button1,button2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                setContentView(R.layout.layout2);

            }
        });

        LayoutInflater inflater=this.getLayoutInflater();

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout2,null);

        button2=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);

        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            }
        });


    }
}
```

These are the layout files to display

**Mainlayout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.lidiawood.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:text="Go to layout 2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:id="@+id/button1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Layout 2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:text="go to main layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/button2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Can any one please help me how can i get display for the mian layout from the componnent of layout 2

Comment: nope getting error

Comment: what is the result?

Answer (score 0):

The onClick event listener is attached to the button in the inflated view, not to the button in the activity view. It doesn't matter that you're using the same layout, it's a different button.

This situation should never happen, because you, generally speaking, need different fragments or activities, when changing the layout. Changing the content view this way is not a good idea. If you still what to use your code, then you need the following:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    onContentViewOneInflated();
}

private void onContentViewOneInflated() {
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            setContentView(R.layout.layout2);
            onContentViewTwoInflated();
        }
    }
}

private void onContentViewTwoInflated() {
    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            onContentViewOneInflated();
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't tried the code. If you have any issues, comment.